# How to use displaymemberpath on a combobox in UWP C++/CX?

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

So I'm trying to bind a combobox to a vector of `myclass`. `myclass` has a public Platform::String^ property called `key`. So in my XAML, I have displaymemberpath for the combobox set to "key". However, I just get a box of empty options, which is the same result as if i set displaymemberpath to "asdf" (a non-existent property). To illustrate my problem, I've tried to rewrite this tutorial on using displaymemberpath in C++/CX: https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2017/01/uwp-combobox-displaymemberpath-and.html (I've tried following the original tutorial in C# and it worked perfectly fine).

Here's my code:

(MainPage.xaml is exactly the same as the tutorial).

```
<Page
    x:Class="displaymembercxxtest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:displaymembercxxtest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel 
        x:Name="stack_panel1" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Background="LightYellow"
        Padding="100"
        >
        <ComboBox 
            x:Name="ComboBox1" 
            Header="Select A Color"
            DisplayMemberPath="ColorName"
            SelectedValuePath="ColorValue"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"
            >
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock1"
            FontFamily="Consolas"
            FontSize="25"
            Foreground="DarkGreen"
            Margin="50,5,5,5"
            />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Code Behind:

```
//MainPage.xaml.h
namespace displaymembercxxtest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainPage sealed
    {
    public:
        MainPage();

    private:
        void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e);
    };
    public ref class color sealed
    {
    public:
        property Platform::String^ ColorName;
        property Platform::String^ ColorValue;
        color(Platform::String^ name, Platform::String^ value)
        {
            ColorName = name;
            ColorValue = value;
        }

    };
}
```

//MainPage.xaml.cpp

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Platform::Collections::Vector<color^>^ colors = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<color^> ();
    colors->Append(ref new color("INDIANRED", "#CD5C5C"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("SALMON", "#FA8072"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("CRIMSON", "#DC143C"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("DEEPPINK", "#FF1493"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("CORAL", "#FF7F50"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("ORANGE", "#FFA500"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("YELLOW", "#FFFF00"));
    colors->Append(ref new  color("PEACHPUFF", "#FFDAB9"));
    ComboBox1->ItemsSource = colors;
}


void displaymembercxxtest::MainPage::ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
   // not relevant to the problem 
}
```

Here is what I'm seeing: 
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I built the tutorial in C#:

[image]

As you can see, the options are blank in the C++/CX version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The XAML code is relevant. It needs to go into your question.

Comment: Like I said it's basically copied and pasted from the tutorial. I added it though, above the MainPage.xaml.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using {Binding}, you'll need to add the [BindableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindableattribute) attribute to the color class.

Please check the following code:

```
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
public ref class color sealed
{
public:
    property Platform::String^ ColorName;
    property Platform::String^ ColorValue;
    color(Platform::String^ name, Platform::String^ value)
    {
        ColorName = name;
        ColorValue = value;
    }
};
```

More information, please read [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#adding-a-details-view) documentation.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Is the displaymembersource property basically using {Binding} behind the scenes or something? Is that tag necessary for {x:Bind}?